# Any way to add CSS for a single page/node?

Tags: php, drupal-7

In particular, my work site's home page is a Panel Page and it has a bunch of different styling. Right now the CSS is just included with the main theme style sheet.

Is there a way to say, "if this is node article, then add article.css"? Is CSS Injector what I'm looking for?

I might be interested in generalizing this to other nodes/sections/etc, but at the moment I just want to handle this one item.

What I ended up doing.

I'm using a bartik subtheme, and discovered in actually reading through template.php that there's some commented out code for including conditional style sheets. Code below did exactly what I needed:

```html
if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
  drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . "/article.css", 'theme','all'); 
}
```

Comment: what you did is the right way to include a css depending on a condition, what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at the [Code per Node](https://www.drupal.org/project/cpn) module.refer the link [here](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/module-monday-code-per-node)

Comment: let me try this